# Set ForeignKey in Django view.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
def clientinfo(request):
    clientForm = ClientInfoForm(prefix="client")
    criminalForm = OCCForm(prefix="criminal")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        clientForm = ClientInfoForm(request.POST,prefix="client")
        criminalForm = OCCForm(request.POST,prefix="criminal")

        criminalForm['cust_id_id'] = clientForm['id']
        
        if clientForm.is_valid() or criminalForm.is_valid():
            clientForm.save()
            criminalForm.save()
            print("SUCCESSFUL SUBMISSION")
            return render(request, 'submitted.html')

    return render(request, 'clientinfo.html',
                  {'form': clientForm, 'occform': OCCForm})
```

My `criminalForm` has a ForeignKey field `cust_id` and i need to set it to the auto-generated Primary key of `clientForm`

I can't figure out the correct way to do this? They both have an associated model `ClientInfo` and `OCC` if I need to use them somehow to accomplish this?

**Models and Forms:**
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select, TextInput, EmailInput, DateInput, NumberInput, CheckboxInput, ChoiceField

class ClientInfo(models.Model):
    SALUTATIONS = (
        (
            ('Miss', 'Miss'),
            ('Mr.', 'Mr.'),
            ('Mrs.', 'Mrs.'),
            ('Ms.', 'Ms.'),
            ('Dr', 'Dr'),
            ('Rev', 'Rev')
        )
    )
    RACE = (
        (
            ('A', 'Asian'),
            ('B', 'Black'),
            ('H', 'Hispanic/Latino'),
            ('N', 'Native American'),
            ('W', 'White')
        )
    )
    GENDER = (
        (
            ('F', 'Female'),
            ('M', 'Male')
        )
    )
    STATE = (
        (
            ('AK', 'Alaska'),
            ('AL', 'Alabama'),
            ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
            ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
            ('CA', 'California'),
            ('CO', 'Colorado'),
            ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
            ('DC', 'District of Columbia'),
            ('DE', 'Delaware'),
            ('FL', 'Florida'),
            ('GA', 'Georgia'),
            ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
            ('IA', 'Iowa'),
            ('ID', 'Idaho'),
            ('IL', 'Illinois'),
            ('IN', 'Indiana'),
            ('KS', 'Kansas'),
            ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
            ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
            ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
            ('MD', 'Maryland'),
            ('ME', 'Maine'),
            ('MI', 'Michigan'),
            ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
            ('MO', 'Missouri'),
            ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
            ('MT', 'Montana'),
            ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
            ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
            ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
            ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
            ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
            ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
            ('NV', 'Nevada'),
            ('NY', 'New York'),
            ('OH', 'Ohio'),
            ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
            ('OR', 'Oregon'),
            ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
            ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'),
            ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
            ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
            ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
            ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
            ('TX', 'Texas'),
            ('UT', 'Utah'),
            ('VA', 'Virginia'),
            ('VT', 'Vermont'),
            ('WA', 'Washington'),
            ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
            ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
            ('WY', 'Wyoming'),
        )
    )
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SALUTATIONS, default='Miss.')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dob = models.DateField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    employer = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    work_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    workphext = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ss_no = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    dl = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    race = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RACE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    opt_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refby_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

# Adding model from database to forms and styling them with bootstrap
class ClientInfoForm(ModelForm):
    case_type = ChoiceField(choices=(('criminal','Criminal'),('domestic','Domestic')), widget=Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id':'case_type'}))

    class Meta:
        model = ClientInfo

        widgets = {
            'salutation': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control col-sm-2'}),
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name*'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name*'}),
            'phone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone Number*', 'data-inputmask': "'mask':'(999) 999-9999'", 'data-inputmask-clearincomplete': 'true'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email Address*'}),
            'dob': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control', 'aria-describedby':'input_dob_label'}),
            'race': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'aria-describedby': 'input_race_label'}),
            'sex': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'aria-describedby': 'input_sex_label'}),
            'address': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Address*'}),
            'city': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'City*'}),
            'state': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'aria-describedby':'input_state_label',}),
            'zip': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Zip*',
                                      'data-inputmask': "'mask':'99999'",
                                      'data-inputmask-clearincomplete': 'true'}),
            'age': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Age*'}),
            'employer': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Employed By*'}),
            'work_phone': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-sm-9', 'placeholder': 'Work Number', 'data-inputmask': "'mask':'(999) 999-9999'", 'data-inputmask-clearincomplete': 'true'}),
            'workphext': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-sm-3', 'placeholder': 'Ext', 'maxlength': "6",}),
            'mobile': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'data-inputmask': "'mask':'(999) 999-9999'", 'data-inputmask-clearincomplete': 'true'}),
            'opt_out': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input'}),
            'refby_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Referred By'}),

        }

        # Dynamically Create Form Fields based on widget details
        fields = []
        for widget in widgets:
            fields.append(widget)
        fields = tuple(fields)

class OCC(models.Model):
    cust_id = models.ForeignKey(ClientInfo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    charge = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    court_date = models.DateField()

class OCCForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OCC

        widgets = {
            'charge': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'court_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'})
        }

        # Dynamically Create Form Fields based on widget details
        fields = []
        for widget in widgets:
            fields.append(widget)
        fields = tuple(fields)
```

**EDIT**

I'm now getting "FORM NOT VALID" in my console when running the code below:

```
def clientinfo(request):
    clientForm = ClientInfoForm(prefix="client")
    criminalForm = OCCForm(prefix="criminal")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        clientForm = ClientInfoForm(request.POST,prefix="client")
        criminalForm = OCCForm(request.POST,prefix="criminal")
        if clientForm.is_valid() and criminalForm.is_valid():
            client = clientForm.save()
            criminalForm.instance.cust_id = client
            criminalForm.save()
            return redirect('submitted.html')
        else:
            print("FORM NOT VALID")
```

**Here's the structure of the OCC table in the database**
[image: The database Structure]

Comment: Can you please share the relevant forms and models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if *both* forms are valid, and after saving the `clientForm`, you can set the `.cust_id` of the `.instance` wraooed in the `criminalForm`:

```
from django.shorcuts import redirect

def clientinfo(request):
    clientForm = ClientInfoForm(prefix='client')
    criminalForm = OCCForm(prefix='criminal')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        clientForm = ClientInfoForm(request.POST, prefix='client')
        criminalForm = OCCForm(request.POST, prefix='criminal')
        if clientForm.is_valid() and criminalForm.is_valid():
            client = clientForm.save()
            criminalForm.instance.cust_id = client.pk
            criminalForm.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')

    return render(
        request,
        'clientinfo.html',
        {'form': clientForm, 'occform': OCCForm}
    )
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `cust`, instead of <s>`cust_id`</s>.

Comment: This actually helps a lot, but I'm getting an error now that says:
ValueError at /clientinfo.html
The OCC could not be created because the data didn't validate.

Is there a way to check why it isn't validating?

Comment: @CodyMitchell: did you change the condition in the `if` to `if clientForm.is_valid() and criminalForm.is_valid()` so with `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: @CodyMitchell: in case the form(s) are not valid, you should *rerender* the template. Forms that are invalid will render the errors. You can also inspect the errors with `print(criminalForm.errors)`.

Comment: I did that  but for some reason it's still not validating. I added the updated code to the bottom of my question.

If it would make it clearer to see the template, the views.py and the models.py I put them on pastebin here: 

models.py:
https://pastebin.com/hxDX9bb2
views.py:
https://pastebin.com/ivRcX2CK
clientinfo.html:
https://pastebin.com/eJPARe6T

Comment: ```criminalForm.instance.cust_id = client.pk```

This fixed it. Thank you so much!